# change html media player position and size upon scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to appear and disappear a div upon user's scrolling effects. Here, I need to shift the position of a strobe media playback upon scrolling. Upon scrolling, the media playback should be shown in a small div (i.e. the first div with `class="node-video--wrapper is_stuck"`). Upon scrolling the large div (i.e. second div should disappear--for which I have written a js function. But as the user reach top the second appears and the first disappears.

Now, the problem is I have put the media player code in both div's. Upon browser loading, the large or second div can't play the player while the smaller div can play it. also, I am having trouble to properly appear and disappear the small or first div. Because upon reaching top, the player starts from the beginning. I am really confused how to do that properly, and I do not any already available js library, if any. Kindly help me with your feedback.

I have included some CSS which I use to resize the media player as the browser size changes.

```
<style type="text/css">

    .containing-block {
      width: 75%;
    }

    .outer-container {
      position: relative;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    }
    #mediaVideoViewPlayer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .node-video .node-video--wrapper.is_stuck {
    z-index: 999999;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #cccccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 19px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 19px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 19px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin-left: -999999px;
    padding-left: 999999px;
    margin-right: -999999px;
    padding-right: 999999px;
}

</style>



<div class="node-video--wrapper is_stuck" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 915px;">
    <a class="close">
        <i class="fa fa-close fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="node-video--player">
        <div id="video-player-top">
            <div style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="containing-block">
                <!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->
                <div id="mediaVideoViewPlayer" class="outer-container"></div>
                <!-- End of Brightcove Player -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="node-video--wrapper">
    <a class="close">
        <i class="fa fa-close fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="node-video--player">
        <div id="video-player-top">
            <div style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="containing-block">
                <!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->
                <div id="mediaVideoViewPlayer" class="outer-container"></div>
                <!-- End of Brightcove Player -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are some js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
     {
        $('#my_scroll').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('#my_scroll').fadeIn();
     }
 });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
     {
        $('.is_stuck').fadeIn();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.is_stuck').fadeOut();
     }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If thing to fix is your jQuery. I added $(function(){}) to your jQuery. Also are you using a jQuery CDN from Google so you can use jQuery? I just do not see that in the code so I have to ask.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
   {
      $('#my_scroll').fadeOut();
      $('.is_stuck').fadeIn();
   }
  else
   {
    $('#my_scroll').fadeIn();
    $('.is_stuck').fadeOut();
   }

  });
</script>
});
```

Comment: hi small or first div shouldn't visible upon loading. It should appear as the user scrolls down and disappears as the user scrolls back to top. Currently, our codes doesn't make that small div disappear when first load.

Comment: @AnayBose I think that you should review your jQuery and HTML a bit more because you do not have an id call my_scroll nor do you have the divs that you want to show and disappear properly marked with CSS so it is very confusing to see what it is that you are looking to do. What I added was merely to get your jQuery working correctly.